# Android CheckBox single selection checked issue

Tags: android, checkbox

I am working on customize expandable list with single selection checkboxes in child.
 I am facing an issue, when single item as a child so checked not working, means checkbox not checked shown. And when there are multiple items as child so checkbox working fine but when it checked first time its fine after unchecked that checkbox not checked again that position.

My XML code

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/lblListCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:button="@drawable/customdrawablecheckbox"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
```

CheckedChange Code:

```
private class onClickCheckBox implements OnCheckedChangeListener {


    public onClickCheckBox () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        lblListCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        if (isChecked) {

        } else {

        }
        lblListCheckBox = (CheckBox) arg0;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting the `checkbox` to false. Change it and use the input value `isChecked` as following

```
private class onClickCheckBox implements OnCheckedChangeListener {


public onClickCheckBox () {
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    listRadioButton = (CheckBox) arg0;
    listRadioButton.setChecked(isChecked);
    if (isChecked) {
      //Do stuff
    } else {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I need a single selection in list. This code is for multiple selection. But thanks for the ans.

Comment: @user123456 what do you mean by single selection and multiple selections!

Comment: Check boxes in list always work like multiple selection process (means we can check multiple checkboxes), But i need to do when 1 check box clicks so if there is other check box checked it will unchecked and current checked checkbox.

Comment: @user123456 then you don't have to deal with `checkbox` at all. Use `RadioButton` instead.

Comment: @user123456 Check out this simple example : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/